# How to clean dataset with specific rules from excel in r

Tags: r, excel

I have a data cleaning question. An example short version of the dataset is below:

```
df <- data.frame(Text1 = c(NA, "Name","Jack","Jack"),
                 Text2 = c(NA, "District","Leon","Leon"),
                 Text3 = c(NA, "School","Black","Black"),
                 Text4 = c(NA, "Grade",1,1),
                 Scoring = c("Text", "Teacher","Ana","Ana"),
                 Item1 = c("11_ada", "/a/","1.0","0.0"),
                 Text7 = c(NA, "/c/","1.0","1.0"),
                 Text8 = c(NA, "/a/","1.0","1.0"),
                 Item2 = c("10_bada", "/x/","1.0","0.0"),
                 Text10 = c(NA, "/y/","0.0","1.0"),
                 Text11 = c(NA, "/z/","1.0","0.0"))

> df
  Text1    Text2  Text3 Text4 Scoring  Item1 Text7 Text8   Item2 Text10 Text11
1  <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  <NA>    Text 11_ada  <NA>  <NA> 10_bada   <NA>   <NA>
2  Name District School Grade Teacher    /a/   /c/   /a/     /x/    /y/    /z/
3  Jack     Leon  Black     1     Ana    1.0   1.0   1.0     1.0    0.0    1.0
4  Jack     Leon  Black     1     Ana    0.0   1.0   1.0     0.0    1.0    0.0
```

The first part of the dataset has demographic information. It has also item information with `correct (1.0)` and `incorrect (0.0)` responses. I am grabbing this information from an excel file. I need to restructure the first two rows as below. Especially, for the Item information, I need to rename them as `1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1 2.2 2.3`. This is just a part of the dataset. Each `Item` has multiple columns and there are many Items.

How can I clean this dataset as below?

> df1

```
      Name District School Grade Teacher    1.1   1.2   1.3     2.1    2.2    2.3
      Jack     Leon  Black     1     Ana    1.0   1.0   1.0     1.0    0.0    1.0
      Jack     Leon  Black     1     Ana    0.0   1.0   1.0     0.0    1.0    0.0
```

Also, how can I get this second desired dataset?

> df2

```
      Name District School Grade Teacher    1.1   1.2   1.3     2.1    2.2    2.3
      NA       NA    NA       NA     NA    11_ada 11_ada 11_ada 10_bada 10_bada 10_bada
      Jack     Leon  Black     1     Ana    1.0   1.0   1.0     1.0    0.0    1.0
      Jack     Leon  Black     1     Ana    0.0   1.0   1.0     0.0    1.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
i1 <- cumsum(grepl("Item", names(df)))
i2 <- match(1, i1)
nm1 <-  make.unique(as.character(i1[i1 > 0]))

 row_to_names(df, 2) %>%
  setNames(make.unique(names(.))) %>%
  rename_with(~nm1, i2:last_col())
```

-output

```
 Name District School Grade Teacher   1 1.1 1.2   2 2.1 2.2
3 Jack     Leon  Black     1     Ana 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
4 Jack     Leon  Black     1     Ana 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
```

---

For the second case

```
i1 <- cumsum(grepl("Item", names(df)))
i2 <- match(1, i1)
nm1 <-  make.unique(as.character(i1[i1 > 0]))
 i3 <- match("Name", df$Text1)
 df[i3, i2:ncol(df)] <- nm1
names(df) <- unlist(df[i3,])
df <- df[-i3,]
i4 <- is.na(df$Name)
df[i4, i2:ncol(df)] <- t(apply(df[i4, i2:ncol(df)], 1, 
  function(x) x[!is.na(x)][cumsum(!is.na(x))]))
```

-output

```
> df
  Name District School Grade Teacher      1    1.1    1.2       2     2.1     2.2
1 <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  <NA>    Text 11_ada 11_ada 11_ada 10_bada 10_bada 10_bada
3 Jack     Leon  Black     1     Ana    1.0    1.0    1.0     1.0     0.0     1.0
4 Jack     Leon  Black     1     Ana    0.0    1.0    1.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
```

Comment: How can I automate the `rename_with()` part by grabbing `Item#` and assign names?

Comment: I actually meant assigning `c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3)` names of the columns

Comment: Can you take a look at this again please, I need to add another row to keep overarching information? Please see the second `df2` desired dataset. `11_ada` and `10_bada`. What modification is needed to add the second row?

Comment: @amisos55 it is already updated